# Java Best way to extract words or (search for characters) from a text file that contains senteces

Tags: java, file, loops, file-read

I am trying to get words out of a text file. The file contains sentences because it is essentially a book. However I am having trouble reading all the characters, and fall into an endless loop. This is what I have to read the txt file.

```
try
{
    File myFile = new File(tale);                 
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);            
}
catch(FileNotFoundException FNFE)
{

}
```

I've been looking online but I am having trouble finding the best way to extract words from the text file. The text file is a book, so there are comas and quotations that should be ignored. However I seem to only get stuck in endless loops. I tried `while(inputFile.hasnext())` but an endless loop occurs. I'm assuming it isn't checking through every character.

I think this would be a good topic to cover for many new programmers bot used to reading from files.

Comment: you need to consume data from your scanner via `scanner.nextLine`, `scanner.next` within your while loop.

Comment: Sorry I dont quite follow? I need the scanner to scan through the file

Answer (score 1):

A scanner refers to the data divided by some delimiter as 'tokens.'  The default delimiter is whitespace.  Calling `scanner.next()` returns the next token.  So, calling `scanner.next` will return the next word or punctuation from your file separated by whitespace.

Like so:

```
File myFile = new File(tale);                 
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
while(inputFile.hasNext())
{
    String next = inputFile.next();
}
```

Check out the [documentation on the Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for more information.